# JavaFX clearing all nodes from anchorpane and adding new nodes during runtime

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, observablelist

I'm having trouble adding nodes back into an `AnchorPane` during runtime.

What i'm trying to do is when a user clicks a button, the current nodes are stored in a `ObservableList<Node>` and then the `AnchorPane` is cleared. After this I need to add new nodes there. Then when the user is done, they click another button and my saved `ObservableList` is supposed to be added back to the `AnchorPane`.

Basically I'm trying to display a customer info form when user clicks on "Customer" button, then display the nodes that were there to start with.

Is there a different way to do this? Without displaying it in another window? 
I used `.addAll()` but that isn't working.

Thanks.

```
private ObservableList<Node> middlePaneContent;
@FXML
private AnchorPane middlePane;
@FXML
private void setMiddlePane(){
    middlePaneContent = middlePane.getChildren();
    //middlePane.setVisible(false);
    middlePane.getChildren().clear();
}
@FXML
private void setInspectionToMiddlePane(){
    //middlePane.getChildren().addAll(middlePaneContent);
    middlePane.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I am confused about your question, but after doing `middlePaneContent = middlePane.getChildren();` then middlePaneContent  and middlePane's children are pointing to the same thing.  If you act on one, the the other will also change - do you need to `clone` the data?

Comment: Yea you are right, how would i make a copy of it instead of pointing to it?

Comment: Not sure what your classes look like but maybe instantiating new ones or maybe `clone` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply storing a reference to `middlePane`'s child list in `middlePaneContent`. Both point to the same list. Clearing one of them will clear the "other".

Use another `List` to store the data:

```
private List<Node> middlePaneContent = new ArrayList<>();

@FXML
private AnchorPane middlePane;

@FXML
private void setMiddlePane(){
    // copy content to another list
    middlePaneContent.clear();
    middlePaneContent.addAll(middlePane.getChildren());

    //middlePane.setVisible(false);

    // clear child list
    middlePane.getChildren().clear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works the first time i do it, but on the second click it gives me this error:                                       
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = AnchorPane[id=Content]

Comment: Never mind i wasn't clearing middlePaneContent before adding the middlePane children. Thank you very much, works perfect now.